# Figuring out if Realm is actually saving the data

Tags: react-native, realm

So I have a large data set that I am trying to save into realm for quick search on the mobile. The data set is roughly 11,000 records that should amount to about 7 MB in size. I have created indexes on the 5 columns that I would like to search on (all string). It seems to me that Realm is saving the data but there is no way for me to verify. Trying to query realm for even a single row causes the app to crash. Note that the same app has another table with much smaller elements that I can access directly.

Can anyone suggest if

1. realm can handle this
2. how can I verify data is saved
3. how to make this perform well

Thanks for any help.

PS I am using react-native version 0.39 with realm 0.15.0 with re-natal latest version

EDIT: I have found out that if I remove encryption on database then no more issues at all and performance is superb (in the order of mseconds to search all records with index). Will try a simpler example to make sure it is not my fault.

Comment: `Trying to query realm for even a single row causes the app to crash.` you should probably find out why that happens. Stack trace?

Comment: Did you figure this out? For viewing the data, if you're on a Mac, you could use [Realm Browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx)